# Send sms when a specific link is sent

Tags: android, ios, mobile, web

Would like to know if there is a way of sending an sms, let's say with orderID etc for an ecommerce site to a dedicated number, when a link is clicked. This will be a mobile web link, so if a specific link is clicked, it'll take body of sms, the number to be sent to and either send it directly or place it in a message app.

Comment: Create an intent with an sms uri which you fire to an sms application?